# Comment appelle-t-on une femme qui est avec un homme qui pourrait être son fils ?

Tags: expressions

Comment appelle-t-on en français une femme qui est avec un homme qui pourrait être son fils ?
Par exemple, le petit ami est très jeune, et la petite amie est très âgée.

J'ai écouté:
http://arteradio.com/son/61657783/vieillir_ensemble (L'amour en charentaises).
À 12min44sec la femme utilise un mot que je n'ai pas compris.

> cougarne 
>   coularne

Ce mot désigne quelqu'une qui est avec un homme qui pourrait être son fils.
Ça peut être un mot charentais (de la Charente).

Comment: A gender-neutral English term for the older party in such “May-December” affairs is [cradle robber/snatcher](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/cradle%20snatcher) but Reverso’s sole French entry for this in context is [mante religieuse](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=cradle+snatcher&langFrom=en&langTo=fr&langTot=en-fr)(praying mantis), which infers no age difference to me at all. I doubt if literal translations as nouns(voleur/voleuse d’un berceau//preneur/preneuse au berceau) are idiomatic, but “[prendre au berceau](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_au_berceau)" is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De part ce que tu as compris je dirais que l'expression est femme cougar. Expression américaine popularisée en France désignant une femme de 35 ans ou plus en général, recherchant des partenaires âgés d'au moins 6 ans de moins qu'elle.

Voici un [article Wikipédia](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar_(femme)) détaillant le terme.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Personnellement, je ne vois aucune connotation négative à ce terme...

Comment: @Random Je comprends. Moi si, c'est que le comportement est jugé inadéquat ou anormal, et donc on le stéréotype à celui d'un animal prédateur. Merci.